# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tr' BeautifulSoup soup.find error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to get the table that is inside the web, and it gives me that error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tr' BeautifulSoup soup.find error
```

url

```
https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/cme-group-benchmark-administration/term-sofr.html
```

code

```
import pip._vendor.requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/cme-group-benchmark-administration/term-sofr.html'
response = pip._vendor.requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

mail_table_div = soup.find('div', class_='mail-table-wrapper')

    th_elements = mail_table_div.find_all('tr')

for th in th_elements:
    print(th.text)
```

get the table from the center of the web

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The website is doing some dynamic rendering to get the table, which is why just trying to parse through the HTML isn't returning anything.

You can do something like

```py
url = "https://www.cmegroup.com/market-data/cme-group-benchmark-administration/term-sofr.html"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
pretty = soup.prettify()
print(pretty)
```

```
python3 out.py > out.html
```

On the website itself, the table is in a div class `main-table-wrapper`. If you try to find that string in `out.html`, it's non-existent.

Looks like the dynamic rendering is done from https://www.cmegroup.com/etc.clientlibs/cmegroupaem/clientlibs/common.41d1922d2e8f96bfba76378b333b2dcd.js.

Best bet is to use Selenium to scrape it, that way you can actually have the Javascript execute and render whatever data the table gets populated with.